# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /hipt/sign.php on line 15

Tags: php, json, get, passwords

I am getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/rainlikq/public_html/script/signupt.php on line 17 the username statement....

can somebody suggest me a solution

I am using it for signup purpose... 
I am trying to execute it ..... 
Actually i am parsing the json data to android device...

```
 <?php

$host="localhost";          //replace with database hostname 
$username="rainlikq_rahul";     //replace with database username 
$password="rahul1";             //replace with database password 
$db_name="rainlikq_rainforest";     //replace with database name

 $con=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 



mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

 if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password2'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['mobile']))
{
 
$username   =   $_POST['username'];
$password   =   $_POST['password'];     
$password2  =   $_POST['password2'];        
$name       =   $_POST['name'];
$mobile     =   $_POST['mobile'];

$result = mysql_query("insert into user(user_email,user_password,name,mobile) values( '$username','$password','$name','$mobile')");
 

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Signed up successfully";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else 
    {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

else
     {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
     }





?>
```

Comment: You are missing a few closing `)`  on line 15- ill let you look harder to find out where they are ..

Comment: If there are a lot of conditions in an if I seperate them. Each or max two conditions in one line. Doing this helps me a lot in my programming life.

Comment: As per your edit; is that your full and actual code? Plus, are you using anything else with this? JS? Ajax? Include?

Comment: **This code will NOT produce that error**. - Not the edit you posted anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### As per your originally posted question without marking as an edit

See: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28117175/1

You forgot to close a few `isset()` calls:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password2'] && isset($_POST['username'] && isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
                                                                                 //^ Here                      ^ And here
```

Just use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password2']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
```

Also since you use the AND operator you can put multiple variables in a `isset()` call like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password2'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['mobile'])) {
```

For more information about `isset()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

And a quote from there:

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

**Side Note:**

1. You use `$username` 2 times, first in your connection and then you assign it new in the if statement (Maybe you will get in trouble with this)

2. You use `mysql_*` API, i would recommend you to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Because: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future.

3. You used the operator `<>`, it's totally okay, but for some people it may seems to be a little bit weird, i would use `!=` and the other operator you can use in your SQL statements

4. I also would recommend you to add error reporting just at the top of your files (only in staging):

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: hi , actually i changed this brackets problem just after posting this question but still getting error....Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/rainlikq/public_html/script/signupt.php on line 18

Comment: @RahulSaxena Try to copy my last code block with only 1 isset call, does it still give you the same error? (Note. you missed to close it 2 times)

Comment: mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

 
if (isset($_POST['name']),isset($_POST['password']),isset($_POST['password2']),isset($_POST['username']),isset($_POST['mobile'])) 
{
 
$username =  $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];  
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$mobile  = $_POST['mobile'];

$result = mysql_query("insert into user(user_email,user_password,name,mobile) values( '$username','$password','$name','$mobile')");
 

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

Comment: @RahulSaxena Just copy this: `if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['password2'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['mobile'])) {` and replace it with your current if statement

Comment: Now i am using this code

Comment: @RahulSaxena No, if you look i only have 1 `isset()` call you have multiple!

Comment: still getting                unexpected '$username'        in the next line.... but why it is switching like this?

Comment: could u plz come on screen share... n tell me the problem if u dont mind @Rizier   on appear.in/traceit

Comment: @RahulSaxena Just edit your question with the edit button under your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28117175/edit and mark line 18 and post the exact error message please! Also write: "EDIT" and show which code you use now to get the error

Comment: @RahulSaxena Also please show us your real and full code!